# so basically when am i allowed back into england?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

okay, so lets say i go to england for 21 days on a standard us passport, can i then (once back in the usa) apply for a long term visa and go back immediantly after i get the visa...so basically when am i allowed back into england?
Also, can i apply for that visa while in england?
ONE MORE, what do i need in order to work at some place like a cafe or something to support myself while there? 
Im 17 btw

Comment: Leaving aside whether you can legally work in the UK (you definitely can’t on any type of visitor visa), you should be aware that the minimum wage for under 18 employees is £4.20 per hour https://www.gov.uk/national-minimum-wage-rates You'd find it extremely difficult to support yourself at that level of income. In the major cities there’s a lot of competition for cafe/bar work eg from UK national and overseas students. You can check what visa you need here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Answer (score 3):

1. You can return immediately after you get the visa
2. You must obtain the visa outside the UK and then re-enter
3. I'm not sure, honestly, if it's possible for you to immigrate on the basis of a non-skilled job. The common employment status, Tier 2, is for skilled workforce.